# Fast open thousands of files in linux/c

Tags: android, c, file-io

I am doing SDCARD scanner which scans each folder and image file.

I am using C code & using opendir, readdir, fopen APIs to enumerate directory and file open. i have dirent, DIR variables.

Problem is fopen() is taking too much time (300 sec for 10000 files) while director traversing is taking ~25 seconds.

Is there any API which allows me to speed up file open operation, using handle, dir_ino or similar so that i can open file using directory handle or similar.

So far i have looked n tried to use dirent->dir_ino, DIR* but no luck.

I m seeking for low-level api which takes lesser time than fopen.

edit
will fts and ftw apis be usefull? they seems to be related to traversing directory only...any other hack or method?

Comment: Before I edit it out, why the Android tag?

Comment: Speed limitations don't come from the API but from the SD card itself.

Comment: @Simon I guess, because it's on an Android system.

Comment: @mouviciel: right, but `fopen` takes a filename, which means it will re-visit the directory listing that the program has just been looking in (potentially several levels deep, therefore scanning several directories). That may or may not cost something significant, you'd sort of hope that either the filesystem or the block device will avoid unnecessary disk (card) activity by caching directory listings. If you're really lucky, Android provides some guarantees that it will.

Comment: @SteveJessop okey dokey, just checking.

Comment: @SteveJessop, thanks, yes i am looking for solution in that direction only...once i reached to leaf directory(where file is located), can i open with just file name using directory or some handle?

Comment: Ok, i admit I was a bit-wtf about this question, but the more i see the comments and a few proposals, the more I'm genuinely intrigued. +1 to the OP. interesting subject.

Comment: I'll second the SD card comment by mouviciel. Before getting too bent out of shape rewriting your code, benchmark it on a real disk. SD cards can be 50x slower than a SATA drive.

Answer (score 1):

The only "low level" function is [`open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open)

```
int fd = open(dirent->d_name, O_RDONLY);
```

Though, `fopen` shouldn't be a lot slower.

Comment: thanks Olaf, above API will return valid fd only if d_name belongs to current working directory. If i call chdir() then it takes almost same time...so is there a way to avoid chdir() or calling open on directory handle.

Comment: @JRC If you want to open the file, there's no way around `open` or `fopen`. You can avoid the `chdir` call of course, if you concatenate the complete path into a character array using `strcpy` and `strcat`.

Comment: how can we use DIR* and struct dirent.d_ino values?

Comment: @JRC You can't. `DIR` has meaning for `readdir` only and ino is a low level file system structure, which might or might not be present. DOS fs has no ino, for example.

Comment: will fts and ftw apis be usefull? they seems to be related to traversing directory only...any other hack or method?

Comment: @JRC I never used these myself, but from the man pages `fts` looks no different than `readdir`, and with `ftw` you must still provide a function, which does open the file.

Comment: Ok. Any idea about file offset or directory offset or even fast file handle?  Thanks

Comment: @JRC No, I'm sorry. The only way is to test, if `fts` or `ftw` is any faster.